# How to remove url from omission dots in WordPress pagination?

Tags: pagination

I am creating a custom pagination with my WordPress. Everything is fine, despite the omission dots are linked to too.

So it creates an anchor with `http:/localhost/wordpress/page/...`.

How can I get to this item and remove the anchor? I check other conditions for different archives and change the links accordingly, but I have not yet found a way to remove this link. Also true for the active page, like so `if ($paged == strval(strip_tags($page))) {…}`.

The query I use:

```
global $wp_query;
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return;
$big = 999999999;
$pages = paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_next' => false,
    'type' => 'array',
));
```

And then I go with some code like this:

```
if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
    echo '<nav aria-label="Pagination">';
    echo '<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
      if ($paged == strval(strip_tags($page))) {
        echo '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">'.$page.'</a></li>';
      } else if (is_author() && !($paged == strval(strip_tags($page)))) {
        echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ).'page/'.str_replace(".","",strip_tags($page)).'">'.strip_tags($page).'</a></li>';
      } else {
        echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$caturl.'page/'.str_replace(".","",strip_tags($page)).'">'.strip_tags($page).'</a></li>';
      }
    }
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '</nav>';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx in advance.

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour of WordPress pagination. What code are you using to output yours?

Comment: I am using a query for the pages in combination with paginate_links and output type of array.

```$pages = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type' => 'array',
    ));```

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a bit around. First I tried a comparison with the `strval` of the `$page`, but then I just thought that the `intval` instead will only be 0 when the omission dots were evaluated.

So I now use this code

```
else if(intval(strip_tags($page)) == 0) {
  echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">'.$page.'</a></li>';
}
```

It does what I wanted it to do. But if anyone knows a better solution I am glad if you'd post it too.